# VS code PowerShell extension intellisense is very slow

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code, intellisense

VS Code PowerShell intellisense has suddenly become very slow for me. It was working fine for a few days. I have uninstalled all extensions, except the one for PowerShell.

Here are the details about VS code.

```
Version: 1.28.2 (user setup)
Commit: 7f3ce96ff4729c91352ae6def877e59c561f4850
Date: 2018-10-17T00:23:51.859Z
Electron: 2.0.9
Chrome: 61.0.3163.100
Node.js: 8.9.3
V8: 6.1.534.41
Architecture: x64
```

Here are the user settings for PowerShell:

> "powershell.bugReporting.project":
>   "https://github.com/PowerShell/vscode-powershell",
>   "powershell.codeFolding.enable": true,
>   "powershell.codeFormatting.alignPropertyValuePairs": true,
>   "powershell.codeFormatting.ignoreOneLineBlock": true,
>   "powershell.codeFormatting.newLineAfterCloseBrace": true,
>   "powershell.codeFormatting.newLineAfterOpenBrace": true,
>   "powershell.codeFormatting.openBraceOnSameLine": true,
>   "powershell.codeFormatting.preset": "Custom",
>   "powershell.codeFormatting.whitespaceAfterSeparator": true,
>   "powershell.codeFormatting.whitespaceAroundOperator": true,
>   "powershell.codeFormatting.whitespaceBeforeOpenBrace": true,
>   "powershell.codeFormatting.whitespaceBeforeOpenParen": true,
>   "powershell.debugging.createTemporaryIntegratedConsole": false,
>   "powershell.developer.bundledModulesPath": "",
>   "powershell.developer.editorServicesLogLevel": "Normal",
>   "powershell.developer.editorServicesWaitForDebugger": false,
>   "powershell.developer.featureFlags": [],
>   "powershell.developer.powerShellExeIsWindowsDevBuild": false,
>   "powershell.developer.powerShellExePath": "",
>   "powershell.enableProfileLoading": true, "powershell.helpCompletion":
>   "BlockComment", "powershell.integratedConsole.focusConsoleOnExecute":
>   true, "powershell.integratedConsole.showOnStartup": true,
>   "powershell.powerShellAdditionalExePaths": [],
>   "powershell.powerShellDefaultVersion": "",
>   "powershell.powerShellExePath": "",
>   "powershell.scriptAnalysis.enable": true,
>   "powershell.scriptAnalysis.settingsPath": "",
>   "powershell.startAutomatically": true, "powershell.useX86Host": false

Does anyone has suggestions?

Comment: What is the OS and PS version? Did you try to reinstall plugin or VScode itself? Did you do any upgrade before it happened?

Comment: There are multiple issues reported [on github](https://github.com/PowerShell/vscode-powershell/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+intellisense+slow) for the issue.  StackOverflow is not the right place for this question.

Comment: Thank you Mike. 
Os version: windows 7.0 
PS version: 5.0 
I did try to re-install the plugin as well as VSCode.

Comment: TheIncorrigible1 didn't find a fix on GitHub, hence the bounty.

Comment: If you open script with powershell_ise, do you have those  intellisense lags too?

Comment: no. ISE works fine.

Comment: Anything to be found in eventviewer?

Comment: Theo, nothing significant in event viewer.

Comment: Seconded @TheIncorrigible1 - this is not the right place for this question.

Answer (score 1):

Since reinstalling VSCode didn't help, it's probably some issue with powershell.

Few things to consider.
I used to experience some lagging with intellisense/ps loading due to some module folders were located on the network drive. I didn't find any better solution rather than copying all modules locally.

I had big issues with PS after upgrading from v3 to v5 on Win 7. Pretty much it stopped working. Downgrading back didn't help. Surprisingly it worked fine if I logged as different user, so I just deleted and recreated my profile and it helped. Log as different user and see if it work differently.

I use VSCode on my linux machine with powershell core (pwsh), as  an ISE alternative. It works good, and I have same version on VSCode as you. Try to install powershell core on your machine and then switch VSCode to use it instead of 5.0
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/core-powershell/vscode/using-vscode?view=powershell-6#using-a-specific-installed-version-of-powershell

Comment: I don't face any issues with intellisense in vscode , running latest build in win 10 with PowerShell 5

Comment: I switched users but no improvement.

Comment: OK, then it should be vscode. Did you update it or powershell recently? Btw, did you check intellisense for other languages, try some c# code, maybe it's not even powershell specific.

Comment: I checked intellisense for MS SQL. It works fine. So, I think it is something to do with PowerShell extension.

Comment: OK. Can you post content of settings.json related to that extension/ Go to file->preference->settings, then open settings.json and type powershell to filter

Comment: How many modules do you have... If you were to remove some of the modules that you have on your machine does it speed it up any? I've had issues in the past with so many modules that Powershell ISE would slow down like this.

Comment: @ thom schumacher, I do have a few modules. Uninstalling a few and see if it helps could be an option. I want to keep it as a last option, since that may affect my work. we do a lot of PowerShell related stuff.

Comment: @MikeTwc, Could not post **User Settings**, since they are far more than 600 characters allowed for the comments.

Comment: @RavilLobo you can post it in your question.

Comment: @MikeTwc even in the question, I could not post settings. They are too many. Let me try to post the settings, I overwrote.

Comment: I think there shoulb be abot 30 settings for ps plugin, just post those. Then I can compare it to mine.

Comment: @MikeTwc I have posed the user settings in the  question. I have removed the comments, to make the post concise.

Comment: @RavilLobo OK, my setting look the same, although I don't see you have "terminal.integrated.shell.windows" parameter in your post (path to powershell.exe), do you have it on settings.json?